# Flex 4 - Technique to allow HTTPService testing locally and on development server

Tags: testing, flex4, httpservice

Right now I have my URLs hard-coded for HTTPService to work with my local machine's web server so that I don't need to copy files to htdocs after compiling. What's a good technique to easily transition HTTPService URLs from working on my testing setup to working with a normal web server setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a service to get the current environment your application is in, similar to how one tests if you're running in AIR or Flex.

In your HTTPService:

```
url="EnvironmentService.getURL1();"
```

In EnvironmentService:

```
public static function getUrl1():URL
{   
     return (LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT)? LOCAL_URL1 : LIVE_URL1;
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, post some more code and we'll work on a solution

Comment: How do you set LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT?

Comment: That's completely up to you when writing EnvironmentService. You can set it at runtime by doing a quick test or you can hard-code it before compilation. For a test, make a request to the local URL, it if fails, try the live URL, if that works, set LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT to false;